# Word Document Replace Text and save to a new file

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've seen a few topics over the web of how to replace text in a Word Document, but my real question is the following: Is Interop the best option? Is there any other (better) option?

Here is an example of a topic I've read [LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1558f560-8ae6-413a-bbc4-aa8d5d912aac/find-replace-in-a-word-document-by-vbnet).

I'm trying to arrange something that will work great on a Web Server, so I'm asking too if you guys could provide some code to get me started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very difficult question to answer since it involves that much opinions about which is best, in any definition of best.

As a starter I would definitely go for VSTO / interop since it is easier to go, and is integrated with and maintained by the developer of both products (Office and Visual Studio).

If your require it to run on a server (with ASP.NET for example) you should **NEVER** use VSTO / interop.

Why?

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) is what Microsoft says about it.

Office interop is not built to run on a server as a process. It is too heavy, and depends on the UI capabilities for rendering, etc. You could use [Open XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735940%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for Word or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for Excel for example.

Comment: Won't I have any issues of using it on a Web Server? Memory limits or/and CPU limits? Imagine it would be used by 800 individuals? Not at the same time, but could happen like 50 at the same time.

Comment: from what I'm seeing, that is for Excel, what about Word? Thanks for the explanation on the Interop, that was what I was afraid...

Comment: @silentw: Another update.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'll give a look at the resources you gave me!