# How to move inbox mails to some other folder in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook

IS there a function which can move mails from inbox to some folder using c#? **I don't want to use any macros.**

Please don't post the answers with macros. I want to crate a service that will move the inbox mails to some other folder.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: What do you mean with 'service'? Outloo isn't a service, and you shouldn't run Office in an ASP.NET web service either.

Comment: I want to create windows service which can move mails from my  inbox to some other folder. I am using outlook webapp for my email account.

Comment: See my answer then. I guess EWS is the best option then.

Comment: Just because people hate outlook they downvote this perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Nishanth S, I'd recommend using scheduled tasks instead of windows services for tasks like this. Much easier to install and update.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio tools for Office gives direct access to a large API (most functions in it are the same as those available in VBA macros).

The appropriate method you are looking for is [`MailItem.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683%28v=office.15%29.aspx). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268996.aspx) explains how to use that method:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = ((Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.
    ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
    (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)).Folders["Test"];

//
// moveMail is a reference to the mail to move (Outlook.MailItem)
//
moveMail.Move(destFolder);
```

You have to create an Office Outlook add-in, and put this code behind a `RibbonButton` `Click` event, or something similar.

Also, take note of the instructions from [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22143024/993547):

> If your require it to run on a server (with ASP.NET for example) you should **NEVER** use VSTO / interop.
>
> Why?
>
> [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) is what Microsoft says about it.
>
> Office interop is not built to run on a server as a process. It is too heavy, and depends on the UI capabilities for rendering, etc. ...

In your case another option might be the use of [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) or other similar solutions from other mail providers.

Comment: VSTO doesn't give access to functions. It provides access to the host application object model which provides properties, events, methods and functions.

Comment: You have to be more specific. According to your explanation it is not clear what functions are.

Comment: Is there any way to override mail if it already exists in the folder and not make a copy of it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to crate a service that will move the inbox mails to some other folder.

I am afraid, you can't use VSTO or just automate any Office application from the service.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article. As a workaround, you may use a low-level API for accessing Outlook emails - Extended MAPI (or any other third-party wrappers around that API).

If you deal with Exchange profiles only, consider using EWS, see  [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

Comment: Actually I didn't update anything except brackets ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public Task MoveToArchive(MailItem selectedItem)
{
   //move the item
   selectedItem.Move(destinationFolderName);
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to add some descriptions for the answer you've posted